# How to make QGraphicsView Flat?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qtstylesheets, qframe

How can I make `QGraphicsView` look flat? It looks like this:

[image]

I don't want the outline to be shown.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QGraphicsView` inherits from `QFrame`. Use the [`setFrameStyle`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qframe.html#setFrameStyle) method and the [`lineWidth`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qframe.html#lineWidth-prop) property to change the frame [appearance](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qframe.html#details).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the stylesheet to customize the look (including the borders) of a QFrame, see the [stylesheet doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qframe).

To make your widget look flat just add this CSS : `border: 0px`